# Get result from MySQL with explode

Tags: php, mysql, explode

i have a row in my user's database for PC information. i separated pc informations with this:

```
||
```

Example of the column:

```
pc|intel||vga|nvidia
```

Now, how i can show all Users with nvidia vga? i don't know how should i use **while** function or anything for this case!

I know how to use **explode** function, but i don't know how i can use this function to get result from database!

i hope you understand my question...

Comment: Well.. You don't know how to use explode correctly if you believe you can fetch results from a DB with this function

Comment: Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: @Daryl Gill, OK, I don't know, but IF you know answer the question and don't send me a spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the MySQL side you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%vga|nvidia%'
```

*Note: Change table_name to the name of your table and change column_name to the name of your column.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get result from DB first, and use explode after.

Comment: How are you accessing your DB (is it Mysql) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    columname LIKE '%|nvidia|%'
```

FYI, you shouldn't store your data in your database this way. It's a poor way to store your data and only causes problems like this. I highly recommend fixing your DB before you're too far gone to fix it.